# How to create an SQL Server 2008 database from script

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to do an Entity Framework walkthrough so I:

- downloaded SQL script here: http://www.learnentityframework.com
- in SQL Server Management Studio, I right-clicked Database, Create Database, named it
- right-clicked on the new database, New Query
- clicked on "Open File" and opened the script file: Create_ProgrammingEFDB1_SQLServer2008.sql
- clicked "! Execute"
- But the script (756K) has been running for 10 minutes now and still says "executing..."

My questions are:

- Is this the **standard way** to read in an SQL script into SQL Server?
- Is it supposed to **take this long**? This is how I would do it in MySQL/PHPMyAdmin it it might take a couple seconds, so I assume I'm not doing something right.

Here is the beginning of the script, I changed the file paths so they point to the right .mdf and .ldf files:

```
****/

--PART ONE  CREATE THE DATABASE. Note the file paths in the first few commands. 
--Change them for your own computer.--
USE [master]
GO

    /****** Object:  Database [ProgrammingEFDB1]    Script Date: 01/28/2009 10:17:44 ******/
    CREATE DATABASE [ProgrammingEFDB1] ON  PRIMARY 
    ( NAME = N'ProgrammingEFDB1', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ProgrammingEFDB1.mdf' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
     LOG ON 
    ( NAME = N'ProgrammingEFDB1_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\ProgrammingEFDB1_log.LDF' , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
    GO

    ALTER DATABASE [ProgrammingEFDB1] SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 90
    GO

    IF (1 = FULLTEXTSERVICEPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled'))
    begin
    EXEC [ProgrammingEFDB1].[dbo].[sp_fulltext_database] @action = 'disable'
    end
    ...
```

### ANSWER:

I had already created a database with the same name so it was trying to create a database that was already there which made it hang for some reason. I deleted that database, reran the script and it completed successfully in 3 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But the script (756K)

Must be a lot more than just a `CREATE DATABASE` in the script, so very hard to say when the script is doing.

You can write progress reports from the script back to the client, or use SQL Profiler to see what commands are being executed.

Comment: it's just CREATE TABLE contact, CREATE TABLE address and a couple procedures, I'm going to just start executing parts of it till I find what it making it hang. But since the book doesn't even mention how to turn this thing into a database, I thought it would be simple...

Comment: "I thought it would be simple": famous last words.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what does your script do exactly in the next `754K`, but the lines you posted seem quite harmless.

Try adding the following to your script:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

This will show queries execution times as they run, and it will help you to locate the problem more exactly.