# Create database from DDL script

Tags: sql-server-2012, ddl

Ok, this might be bit silly question but I can't seem to find any viable reference to what I need.

I'm going through NHibernate tutorial and with code I got this DDL scripted database. I know few facts on DDL but never worked with it to be honest. So I have no idea how to create a database from it on my server. Of course, I've just tried running it but nothing happens (as expected eh...).

Note: I'm running SQL Server 2012.

Please do help even if this might be too stupid to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: did u try looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602768/how-to-create-an-sql-server-2008-database-from-script

Comment: Yes. That exact one(among others). But most of the questions/tutorials I've encountered are referring to .sql scripts. Are ddl scripts the same? That's what makes it troublesome... I could possibly recreate this database by reading the script but there are lots of those, so I figured there must be a way to generate it from the given file (create_database.ddl namely).

Answer (score 2):

"DDL" stands for "Data Definition Language"; it's a blanket term for SQL statements that create and modify schema objects — statements like `CREATE TABLE ...` and `ALTER TABLE ...` and `CREATE INDEX ...` and so on. (It's as opposed to "DML", "Data Manipulation Language", which is SQL statements that merely modify the data *in* those objects — statements like `INSERT INTO ...`, `UPDATE ...`, and `DELETE ...`.)

Your `.ddl` file is probably just an ordinary SQL script consisting of DDL statements; the extension `.ddl` is for the benefit of human readers, so they know what kind of SQL script it is. But if you know how to run a `.sql` script, then you can probably run your `.ddl` script in the same way.

(If you're worried, you can first try opening your `.ddl` file in Notepad, and confirming that what it consists of is `CREATE TABLE ...`–type statements, before actually running it in your database.)

Comment: Well that's just it. I did open it. And ran it as usual figured nothing special about it, it even ran perfectly without errors, but it didn't create anything... Which threw me off quite a bit, so I thought maybe it's because it's ddl...

Comment: @user1407758: Then -- nope, it's *not* because it's DDL. Something else is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the script that creates the database, it should be on this format

```
CREATE TABLE <table name> ( 
    <attribute name 1> <data type 1>,
    ...
    <attribute name n> <data type n>
    );
```

- replace the angle brackets AND its content entirely with your values*

reference: http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=ddldml.php
best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This may sound dumb, but I recently did something very similar in mssqlmm and was quite confused as to why I could not find the new created database from the script I had just run.  Turns out I just had to click the refresh button on the left hand pane before it showed up in the databases tree.